# Why does the Anchor still use the default css even I styled it differently (GWT)?

Tags: css, gwt

In Gwt, we have these default css for Anchor:

In css file

```
.gwt-Anchor:link {color:black;}
.gwt-Anchor:visited {color:#00FF00;}

.gwt-Anchor:active {
    color:#0000FF;
}

.gwt-Anchor:hover {
    color:#FF00FF;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

That means whenever i created a new Anchor, it will use the default.

But i want a custom one with blue color. That is I want everything is exactly the same as default Anchor except that the Anchor is blue.

So I created these:

```
.blueAnchor:link {color:blue;}
.blueAnchor:visited {color:#00FF00;}

.blueAnchor:active {
    color:#0000FF;
}

.blueAnchor:hover {
    color:#FF00FF;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

Then in Java file

```
Anchor loadMoreAnchor=new Anchor("Load More");

loadMoreAnchor.addStyleName(getView().getRes().css().blueAnchor());
```

Nothing happened to loadMoreAnchor as it still use the default Amchor css.

What is the problem? If you can fix it, can you ALSO tell me how to do to avoid duplicated css code. Look at `gwt-Anchor` & `blueAnchor`, they are the same but have 1 different. We cold do things like:

```
.blueAnchor:link {color:blue;}
.gwt-Anchor:link {color:black;}
.gwt-Anchor:visited, .blueAnchor:visited {color:#00FF00;}

.gwt-Anchor:active, .blueAnchor:active {
    color:#0000FF;
}

.gwt-Anchor:hover, .blueAnchor:hover {
    color:#FF00FF;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

But I am not sure i am doing correctly.

Note: This is the actual javascript code of loadmore anchor: `<a class="gwt-Anchor GEMVVLYDKI" href="javascript:;">Load More</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "!important" to your styles.

You add your own style definitions, but GWT still applies its own standard styles, and they win. You either have to override these styles in the GWT CSS, or mark your own styles as "!important".

EDIT:

You have to specify all pseudo-classes that you want for your links:

```
.blueAnchor:link {color:blue !important;}
.blueAnchor:visited {color:#00FF00 !important;}
.blueAnchor:active {color:#0000FF !important;}
.blueAnchor:hover {color:#FF00FF !important;}
```

You don't need to include the other properties that you did not change (e.g. cursor).

This is why I prefer to copy GWT's standard CSS into my own CSS file, and then I *do not* include a standard GWT style in my application. This way I can make changes in one file only, and there are no conflicts between two different style sheets.

Comment: Hi, it working BUT all the other default style were dissapear? it means the Anchor is blue but when i mouse over It didn't turn to Pink like the default one.

Comment: This is how pseudo-classes work in CSS. You have to specify all of them. See an update.

Comment: why can't be ".gwt-Anchor:visited, .blueAnchor:visited {color:#00FF00;}", if i do like u then we got duplicate css code?

Comment: Because !important after color property in .blueAnchor will override the color in .blueAnchor:visited.

Answer (score 0):

CSS would be

```
.gwt-Anchor:link {color:black;}
a.blueAnchor:link {color:blue;}

.gwt-Anchor:visited,
a.blueAnchor:visited{color:#00FF00;}

.gwt-Anchor:hover,
a.blueAnchor:hover {
    color:#FF00FF;
    cursor: pointer;     
}

.gwt-Anchor:active,
a.blueAnchor:active {
    color:#0000FF;
}
```

Please find helpful jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9GLG8/1/

Comment: then it will mess up with existing "a" style

Comment: if you look carefully I have used styles which are all ready there defined by you. I have just reframed CSS in such a way that a.gwt-Anchor and a.blueAnchor will appear as per styles defined also as we are not defining any styles as a:link or a:visited etc so it wont affect to other anchors than these two classes

Answer (score 0):

Please show html output. It would be difficult to see if you are referencing the a tag directly or the element it resides in.
@pravin's answer might work but its difficult to say for sure.
"A" tags have their own set of css rules by default which means they dont pick up the parent rules by default.

Comment: Ok just so i understand, the problem is that the styles you have implemented above are not showing at all? or that there is an overriding style and it wont change.
If you are overriding then make sure to use the !important after the style to ensure its used over everything else.
for instance background-color:#fff !important; is used instead of background-color:#000;

Comment: maybe gwt problem not css

Comment: i edited my answer. Well css is interoperated by the browser. make sure to use developer tool in your browser to make sure everything is running smoothly. do you have a live example i can look at?

Comment: I want a proper way to do, i don;t want to use code that i feel not like a right way why we have to use "a.blueAnchor"? cos een it may work but it can break in the future cos it like hacking code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of using !important for things like this, since it's too blunt an instrument.

The rule in the theme "wins" because it arrived after your CSS, and therefore any conflicting rules got overridden by the incoming theme.

Try adding html or html body to the beginning of your rule, as in:

html body .gwt-Anchor:link {color:black;}

That will give the rule more priority, since it's more complex than the rule in the theme